# prolog display weight

Tags: prolog

How would I program a rule in prolog that will allow it to print a list of the edge cost/weight between two nodes?

My edge facts are entered as

```
edge(X,Y,Weight).
edge(Y,X,Weight).
```

Comment: Do you want to do something like a routing algorithm? And tbh, this question is kinda short and doesn't explain your needs at all.

Answer (score 0):

In short you want a rule that will search all `edge` facts for a match starting from `X to Y` and print the weight cost associated to that.

If you are sure that there is a backwards fact for every node (that practically means for every fact `edge(X,Y,Edge_Weight)` there should exist a fact `edge(Y,X,Edge_Weight)` in your code) and supposing that the weight between those two edges is not different as you have provided then here is a code that will print the weight cost of all possible edges between `X and Y`:

```
  find_edge_weight(X,Y, [D]):-
                 edge(X, Y, EdgeCost), /* Checking for an existing edge */
                 find_edge_weight(X,Y,[EdgeCost|D]), /* Adding weight to the list */
                 printList([D]). /* Printing list */

  /* A rule used to print the list */
  printList([EdgeCost|D]):-
                 write_ln(EdgeCost),
                 printList(D).
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a path predicate like this one :

```
path(Node1,Node2,W,Path_Weight) :- edge(Node1,Node2,Tmp), Path_Weight = W+Tmp.
path(Node1,Node2,W,Path_Weight) :- edge(Node1,NextNode,A), path(NextNode,Node2,A+W,Path_Weight).
```

This should provide you the solution in Path_Weight variable.
Hope it helps.

Comment: standard Prolog would require `Path_Weight is W+Tmp` and a temporary for `A+W`, for instance `T is A+W, path(NextNode, Node2, T, Path_Weight)`